# Практическое применение DI в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

Есть ли открытые проекты в которых можно увидеть практическое применение DI? Ну или приведите конкретный пример как лучше использовать этот подход и где он нужен, а где это лишнее.

Comment: как работает DI и IoC в ларавел
https://gist.github.com/greabock/02c13c428304c5ce9ec4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой пример это маршрут, когда твой метода контроллера перехватывает id в маршруте и преобразовывает его в необходимый класс

```
Rote::get('/user/{user}','UserController@show');
```

UserController.php

```
public function show(App\User $user) {
  //переменная $user сразу содержит необходимый экземпляр     
}
```

А вообще в Ларавел сейчас они везде: Events, Listeners и в других часто используемых классах, это ничто иное как внедрение одного класса в другой класс через конструктор или сеттером

Пример:

```
class SendingService {
    private $sendService;

    public function __construct(Sending $smsService) {
        $this->sendService = $smsService;
    }

    public function send($message) {
        return $this->sendService->send($message);
    }
}

interface Sending {
    public function send($message);
}

class SmsService implements Sending {}

class EmailService implements Sending {}
```

Comment: Это использование именно того что предоставляет сам фреймворк, интересней взглянуть например на пакет рассылки смс где с помощью DI можно подменять то чем отправляем

Comment: @Shadow33 Может названия выбрал не очень но идея думаю ясна ?

Comment: Да принцип понятен. https://habrahabr.ru/post/206442/ вот еще нашел по своему запросу. Может будет интересно.